# Wrong difference when calculating the difference between the present day and another date

Tags: javascript, date, difference

I need your help.

My code is not returning the proper differential value when calculating the difference between the present date minus another date (UK Date Standard)

Ex.

The correct answers should result to:

```
30/01/2015 - 30/01/2015 = 0
30/01/2015 - 29/01/2015 = 1
30/01/2015 - 31/01/2015 = -1
```

Current code:

```
var x = "30/01/2015"
var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
var today = new Date();
var secondDate = new Date(x);

var diffDays = Math.ceil((secondDate.getTime() - today.getTime())/(oneDay));

alert(diffDays)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new Date("30/01/2015").toSTring()` will return "Thu Jun 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)".

The date string format you pass must wether be http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15 or https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14

You can also put it this way `new Date(2015,0,30);`

More informations here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 0):

Your date string variable `x` is in wrong format.

From constructor's parameters part of [Date object description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

> dateString
>
> String value representing a date. The string should be in a format
>   recognized by the Date.parse() method (IETF-compliant RFC 2822
>   timestamps and also a version of ISO8601).

Use

```
var x = '2015-01-30'
```

[JSFiddle for your case](http://jsfiddle.net/hcjzw7fk/).